# External List (List view) change layout to multiple columns

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, page-layout, external-list

I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

I have an external list.

In the list view, I want to add 3 web parts horizontally. (side by side)
That means I need to change the page layout. But couldn't find where to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You add WebPart zones to your list view. This can be done in various ways. For example using SharePoint Designer or just edit your view aspx form in the explorer.

The Explorer way:

Go to your External List using the explorer or use the `Open With Explorer button`.
If the open with explorer button is **not available** for the external list, try using an other list and then browser in the explorer to your external list folder or use 
`\\host\Lists\[YourList]` or `\\hosts\sites\[YourSite]\Lists\[YourList]` .

[image: Open with explorer]

In the explorer edit the aspx of your viewform using an editor of your choice.

You can now add new webpart zones to the following piece

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
 <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main" />
</asp:Content>
```

For example for a three column form you can use the following code

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Middle" Title="Middle" />
  <td/>
  <td>
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Right" Title="Right" />
  <td/>
 </tr>      
</table>
```

Save your form and edit your page in the browser

Now you have multiple columns with multiple webpart zones
[image: Example]
**Tested in SP2013**

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't look like it's SP 2013.. I'm on SP 2013 standard. I cannot add webpartzones to the page, SP designer doesn't like it, and it removes it. and there isn't a open with explorer button.

Comment: Tested in SP2013 and it worked. If there is no explorer button use an other list to open in explorer. Updated anwer with methods to go to the external list